# Symmetry on Bohr's Hydrogen Atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, hydrogen, orbitals

I was studying the applications of the Schröedinger wave function in the Bohr's atom.

For what I understood, the $\psi$ should only depend on r and not on $\theta$ and $\phi$. Does that mean that $\psi(r, \theta, \phi)=R(r)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the wavefunction depends on all the coordinates. However, there are special states called $s$ states, without any angular momentum, where it depends only on $r$.

Comment: And there is a symmetry in the $1/r^2$ potential that makes that other values of the angular momentum quantum number have the same energy.